# How can we find the recent record from each group in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find out most recent record from each group.
My collection:-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "loginID" : Ram.1234@gmail.com , "name" : Ram, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z"),Site:blog.com,opertion:modified }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z").site:ketanblog.com,opertion:updated }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "loginID" :Ram.1234@gmail.com , "name" : Ram, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z"),Site:blogtec.com,opertion:modified }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-08T00:00:00Z"),Site:blogpec.com,opertion:updated }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-07T00:00:00Z") ,Site:blog.com,opertion:read}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "loginID" : shyam78@gmail.com, "name" : Shyam, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-09T00:00:00Z"),site:ketanblog.com,opertion:deleted }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7"), "loginID" : shyam78@gmail.com, "name" : Shyam, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z") ,site:ketanblog.com,opertion:updated}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("8"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z"),Site:blogtrt.com,opertion:read  }
```

My Expected output:-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "loginID" : Ram.1234@gmail.com, "name" : Ram, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z"),Site:blogtec.com,opertion:modified  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "loginID" : Arjun34@gmail.com, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-08T00:00:00Z"),Site:blogpec.com,opertion:updated  }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "loginID" : shyam78@gmail.com, "name" : Shyam, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-09T00:00:00Z"),Site:ketanblog.com,opertion:deleted  }
```

Comment: Sort by time before grouping, then use $first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$sort` by date descending order
- `$group` by `loginID` and add first recent document in `recent`
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `recent` into new root
- `$sort` new grouped documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$loginID",
      recent: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$recent" } },
  { $sort: { date: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TRV68HGMYla)

Comment: Thanks,I got the recent dates from each group but now I want to arrange the recent dates with increasing order means older recent date of individual group come on the top with all field then another recent date of individual group and so on

Comment: you can check now updated answer, is that you want?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort by date to keep the latest data for each group at the top
2. Group by login id, get the first record for each group which is latest. It discards other records in each group

```
db.coll.aggregate([
{
  $sort : {"$date": - 1}
}, 
{
 $group: {
   _id : "$loginID", 
  data : { 
    $first : "$$ROOT" 
  } 
 } 
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks,I got the recent dates from each group but now I want to arrange the recent dates with increasing order means older recent date of individual group come on the top with all field then another recent date of individual group and so on

Comment: Can you explain with sample output and it seems not part of your primary question